# How to turn the laptop built-in webcam on/off from shell

Tags: linux, shell, webcam

`Fn`+`F6` key combination turns my laptop's integrated web camera on/off. Looking at the `dmesg` output, it seems that the webcam (USB device) is being more or less virtually connected/disconnected to/from the USB bus:

```
usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0203
usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-5: Product: BisonCam, NB Pro
usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Bison Electronics Inc.
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device BisonCam, NB Pro (5986:0203)
input: BisonCam, NB Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input14
usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

The first seven lines come after "connect" and the last line is after "disconnect" event. `dmesg` timestamps removed for clarity.

`showkey` executed from a tty console returned keycode 214, `xev` from KDE returned keycode 220 and also `XF86WebCam`. Here's the part of `xev` output related to pressing the `Fn`+`F6`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xac, subw 0x0, time 78270130, (346,354), root:(348,377),
    state 0x0, keycode 220 (keysym 0x1008ff8f, XF86WebCam), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I've already tried sending the keycode of the `Fn`+`F6` combination (either 214, 220 or XF86WebCam) using the `xdotool`, `xvkbd` and `xmacro`, but with no success.

Probably the right way to do it is not by using the keycodes at all.

Comment: Note: I don't have a real-life use case for this. It's just my curiosity (: So, no workarounds like disabling/enabling the driver and/or the USB hub are of any help.

Comment: I had to reboot to Win7 and hit Fn+F6 to re-enable my camera (don't know what disabled it in the first place) and then reboot back into Ubuntu. Would love to have a "Ubuntu-only" solution.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command with root permissions:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/authorized
```

The path is taken from `dmesg`'s output:

```
input: BisonCam, NB Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input14
```

This will forbid the system to have access to your device without deactivating neither the whole bus nor the uvc driver, and no reboot required.

To reactivate, run `echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/authorized` (again with root permissions).

Note: I use Archlinux with Linux 4.17

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this using `modprobe` interactively on the command line. You may be able to blacklist it and then reboot or resource in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I just found [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-disable-my-webcam) which may provide some more detail, since I don't have a system up with a webcam in front of me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried it, but as I suspected, this doesn't help. It would only work if the webcam was already switched on, but if webcam is off this method won't turn it on. For a webcam to work at least two conditions must be met: (webcam on) AND (driver loaded). The post from AskUbuntu deals with the second and I'm interested in the first "switch".

Comment: I think the keyboard shortcut with the function keys maybe be outside the scope of the operating system's control. I would imagine you would want it switched on in hardware, and then by default have it blacklisted, turning it on manually (?)

Comment: Maybe it would work one-way: to turn on the webcam, but if a process is currently using it, you can't remove the webcam's driver. Another solution would be `sudo echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind` to disable and `sudo echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind` to enable the USB port the webcam is connected to. This is what I use to "reset" the webcam if it hangs. **Note: this also temporarily disconnects other devices that may be connected to the same hub!** The card reader in my case.

Comment: Correction: Disabling `ehci_hcd` puts all of the High-Speed (2.0) USB devices into Full-Speed (1.1) mode. It does not disable the USB hub.